# cshtml, jquery, Click parent cell does nothing unless I click elsewhere firsth

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

In an mvc application, in the view, i build a table of multiple cells, all withe same css class, to which i add a click event that pop-up a window. So clicking on a cell, open a modal pop-up window.

The code that opens the pop-iup

```
$('.EmployeeEvent').unbind('click').click(function () { 
    ...
    var oEditEventWindow = $("#WndEditEvent").data("kendoWindow");

        oEditEventWindow.open().center();
        oEditEventWindow.refresh({
            url: "/EmployeeScheduler/EmployeeScheduler/GetEditEventViewModel",
            data: {
               ...
            }
        });

    oEditEventWindow.title(...);
});
```

I can then, either cancel, close the window, or use it to enter some data and submit, and the upon a successful save in the application/db, refresh the content of that particular cell, based on the operation and the pop-up window closes.

```
$("#btn-Cancel").click(function () {
    $("#WndEditEvent").data("kendoWindow").close();
});

$("#btn-Add").click(function () {
    ManageEvent(iSAVE);
});

$("#btn-Modify").click(function () {
    ManageEvent(iSAVE);
});
```

The problem is that if i pop-up the window and cancel, i actually can re-pop up it by clicking on the cell and repeat as many times. If i submit from the pop-up (instead of canceling), the window closes, re-clicking on that cell does NOTHING (IT DOES NOT re pop-up the window!!!!). I actually have to click elsewhere, and then cancel to be able for the click on the initial cell to work.

```
function ManageEvent(iRequestType) {
 ...
  $.ajax({
    url: "/EmployeeScheduler/EmployeeScheduler/ManageEvent",
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        ...
    },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == '-1') {
            $('#GeneralError').show();
       ...
        else {

           // DO SOMETHING THEN CLOSE WINDOW
            // Update the status panel (i.e. display and buttons)

            $("#WndEditEvent").data("kendoWindow").close();

        }
    }
  });
}
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have missed out binding events inside document.ready. Try the following code snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.EmployeeEvent').unbind('click').click(function (){
                 // some logic
            });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - actually you pointed me to the right direction. I did the unbind and bind in the close window location post the ajax call and it worked :-)

Comment: Welcome, u can thank me actually by clicking on **Accept** ... :)